# Why does my computer no longer recognize keyboards?

Tags: windows-8, usb, boot, keyboard, post

This is an Asus All-in-One from 2010 running Windows 8.

The computer froze. Upon reboot, the keyboard was not detected and would not power up (the lights would not activate as they usually do.) I tried every USB slot to no avail. The keyboard works properly on other computers. I tried a different, working keyboard and that, too, doesn't work. However, when I plug in other devices (like my phone) into a USB slot, it starts to charge.

The machine POSTs fine.

I can't get past the Bitlocker password screen, for obvious reasons.

Anyone have any idea as to what's goin on here? I'm pretty desperate.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems likely that the system froze because of the very same hardware problem that's now preventing it from recognizing a keyboard.

Comment: Do you have any Comcast/Constant Guard software on that machine?